# BATCH (win) - stop when multiple txt files exist

Tags: windows, random, batch-file

okay so i am making a random generator in batch, and it works. but i want it to stop when it has made 5 different random numbers. so i set the random numbers making txt files when they have been generated, and i want a maximum of 5 text files until the bat stops it.

```
:go
set go=%random%
title GENERATING %go%
if /i %go% lss 1 goto go
if /i %go% gtr 7 goto go
if exist goal%go%.txt goto go
goto go

:obje1
set goal1="11111"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go

:obje2
set goal_2="22222"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go

:obje3
set goal_3="3333"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go

:obje4
set goal_4="4444"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go

:obje5
set goal_5="55555"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go

:obje6
set goal_6="6666"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go

:obje7
set goal_7="7777"
echo lol > goal%go%.txt
goto go
```

i was thinking if i could put in the :go something similar to this
`if exist equ 5 *.txt goto done`

but that didnt work

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a counter.  Also, you can restrict your random number generator to a number between 1 and 7 as shown below.

```
set count=0
:go
if %count%==5 exit /b
set /a go=%random% %% 7 + 1
...
goto go

:obj1
set /a count=%count%+1
...
goto go
```

Answer (score 1):

Some caveats and recommmendations.

1. You can make a counted loop with `FOR /L` command. See `HELP FOR`.
2. `%RANDOM%` returns a random number between 0 and 32767. You may set the limits of your generated random integer with simple arithmetic. See `HELP SET`. Because of the range of `%RANDOM%`, the modulo operation suggested by Hand-e-food, will produce an small skew. So it is better to use division.
3. Finally, setting a variable inside a loop only works with delayed expansion `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and using the `!XXX!` syntax. See `HELP SET`.

So, putting all pieces together, try this

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
  SET /A go=!random!*7/32768
  SET /A go=!go!+1
  echo %%i .- !go!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking from PA

If your goal is simply create 5 .txt files with random numbers, then you can accomplish this in the `FOR /L` loop:

```
FOR /L %%F IN (1,1,5) DO (
 ECHO LOL>"file!random!.txt"
)
```

Now if you need to keep track of what files were generated, we can throw them into a "File List"

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%F IN (1,1,5) DO (
 SET go=!random!
 ECHO LOL>"file!go!.txt"
 ECHO file!go!.txt>>"File List.txt"
)
```